# Matlab: Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Tags: matlab

For matlab, I keep getting the following error 
"Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts"

why? I tried looking it up, but it makes no sense to me at all.

```
 prefix = {'Bark', 'Bush', 'Fabric', 'Floor',...
      'Flower', 'Food', 'Gravel', 'Hair',...
      'Marble', 'Metal', 'Paint'};


for a = 1: 9
    for b = 1:11

    fn = sprintf('%s.%d.png', prefix{a}, b);
    fn(a,b) = fn;
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`fn` in your loop is originally a string that is 1D, but then you're reusing the same variable and assuming it's a 2D array of some kind which is why you're getting that error.  There isn't enough room to do what you want in `fn`.  I think you mean to have an additional output cell array that is 2D that will store these strings.

Allocate this at the beginning of your loop and use that instead.  Something like this:

```
prefix = {'Bark', 'Bush', 'Fabric', 'Floor',...
      'Flower', 'Food', 'Gravel', 'Hair',...
      'Marble', 'Metal', 'Paint'};

out = cell(9, 11); % Change
for a = 1:9
    for b = 1:11
        fn = sprintf('%s.%d.png', prefix{a}, b);
        out{a,b} = fn; % Change
    end
end
```